# Using ONT MinION, why is that we cannot get a full length DNA read?

Tags: nanopore, long-reads, minion

Here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9-Rm5AoZGw, ONT claims they can read non-fragmented DNA and that with the hairpin like structure the double strands can be read at once. Then why is that MinION reads are of variable in length and not the length of a whole DNA? BUt here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9wtAIvPPxY, ONT claims that the read lenght can be configured, what does this mean?

Comment: The MinION will read the full length of the the fragments which pass through the pore. Are you asking why it can't read the full genome in one go?

Answer (score 2):

The MinION should be able to sequence DNA fragments entirely, regardless of the size, if you can get them to the pore intact. That is the problem: during DNA extraction and library preparation you will introduce breakage.